# AngularJS view works first time clicked, but not second time

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome-app

- I am using the Metronic Admin template (AngularJS version)
  http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469
- I am developing a Chrome App with this template

I have a page/view inside this Chrome App where you can view the ban list of our website.

The ban list loads the first time, but not the second time you click ´Ban List´ in the sidebar. Second click means here when you go to another view (Dashboard for example) and you go back to Ban List.

Snippets of files:

**app.js:**

```
        // All Bans
    .state('allbans', {
        url: "/all_bans.html",
        templateUrl: "views/all_bans.html",
        data: {pageTitle: 'User Ban List'},
        controller: "GeneralPageController",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'MetronicApp',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                    files: [
                        '/assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.css',                             
                        '/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.css', 
                        '/assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/Scroller/css/dataTables.scroller.min.css',
                        '/assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/ColReorder/css/dataTables.colReorder.min.css',

                        '/assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.min.js',
                        '/assets/global/plugins/datatables/all.min.js',
                        'js/scripts/table-advanced.js',

                        '/js_custom/all_bans.js',

                        'js/controllers/GeneralPageController.js'
                    ] 
                }]);
            }]
        }
    })
```

**all_bans.js:**

```
chrome.storage.local.get('userkey', function (result) {
var userkey = "";
userkey = result.userkey;
console.debug('userkey :', userkey);
chrome.storage.local.get('username', function (resultt) {   
    var username = "";
    username = resultt.username;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "URL HIDDEN/api/allbans.php?userkey=" + userkey + "&username=" + username,
        success: function(msg){
            $('.ajaxscriptsimm').html(msg);
            //document.getElementsByClassName("banknop").addEventListener("click", LoadPagebanpage);
        }
    });
});
```

});

**all_bans.html:**

```
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
        <div class="row" ng-controller="GeneralPageController">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="ajaxscriptsimm">
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->
```

First click:
[image]

Second click:
[image]

These errors are present in the Chrome (but seem to occur when opening the dashboard, not the bans list):

```
 Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

angular.min.js:92 EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

at eval (native)
at chrome-extension://mlpdcfkafmhfaancdijopanidfkagbod/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js:2:2620
at Function.m.extend.globalEval (chrome-extension://mlpdcfkafmhfaancdijopanidfkagbod/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js:2:2631)
at m.fn.extend.domManip (chrome-extension://mlpdcfkafmhfaancdijopanidfkagbod/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js:3:23046)
at m.fn.extend.append (chrome-extension://mlpdcfkafmhfaancdijopanidfkagbod/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js:3:20507)
at null.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://mlpdcfkafmhfaancdijopanidfkagbod/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js:3:22038)
at m.access (chrome-extension://mlpdcfkafmhfaancdijopanidfkagbod/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js:3:3286)
at m.fn.extend.html (chrome-extension://mlpdcfkafmhfaancdijopanidfkagbod/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js:3:21623)
at e [as html] (chrome-extension://mlpdcfkafmhfaancdijopanidfkagbod/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js:25:207)
at chrome-extension://mlpdcfkafmhfaancdijopanidfkagbod/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:21866 <div ui-view="" class="fade-in-up ng-scope">
```

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the page to see if there are any errors in the console? You can do so through `chrome://inspect/#apps`

Comment: Yes, I have updated my post with the errors from the console. However, these errors seems  to occur when I click the Dashboard (or when the Dashboard loads when the app starts), there are no errors when loading the ban list.

Comment: Looks like you need a CSP fix for Angular in Chrome apps.

Comment: AngularJS should automatically work with Chrome Apps CSP (?)
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp

Comment: Hm, you're right, that's an error that Angular corrects for automatically, but you can avoid it altogether with the directive you mentioned. Anyway, indeed it seems not to be the reason.

Comment: Extra info: when clicking the second time, the page all_bans.html does not do ´ XHR finished loading: GET´ again.